# How can I send a push notification when the app is closed?

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification, local

I would like to send a simple local push notification which says the following when the app is closed for whatever reason;

"You've been logged out of iDHSB"

How would I do this?

Taken a look at Apple's resources but it was a bit involved and thought that the code could be much shorter for what I want to do...

Thanks,

James

Comment: Like Henrik said, I think you should really reconsider adding that.

Comment: This sounds like an app that I would immediately delete.

Comment: good you won't be using it then...

Comment: He didn't ask for your opinions. Maybe he's a doctor who needs to know immediately if he's lost connection to his patient. He needs to have that dialog pop up now!!! Even if it's not he's going to hear from his users what it is they want. It may be an optional feature. You don't know. We don't know. This is a question and answers site not a question and opinions site. (ranting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beside some serious violation of every users comfort level you could achieve that by using [local notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html).

> Local notifications are scheduled by an application and delivered by
>   iOS on the same device.

Comment: Is there some sample code that I can use because this looks a bit overly complicated for what I want to do?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW13

Comment: That link is outdated. The new link is http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html